# How to fix this white space while showing two div boxes beside each other?

Tags: html, css, web-development-server

[Two div boxes(purple, pink), how to fix that white space above pink box?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGPWe.png)

HTML Code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lecture 3</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <main>
        <div class="box1"> man </div><div class="box2"> man2 </div>
    </main>
        
    <footer>
        <div class="foot">
            Copyright © Mayank Daga
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code for the div part

```
.box1{
    background-color: violet;
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Baloo Bhai 2', cursive;
    height:120vh;
}

.box2{
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Baloo Bhai 2', cursive;
    height:120vh;
}
```

I expect that there must not be any white space, it must be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

`flex` with `row` direction and `align-items: flex-start` should work here.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 50%;
  height: fit-content;
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhai 2', cursive;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: violet;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lecture 3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box box1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries</div>
      <div class="box box2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries</div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="foot">
      Copyright © Mayank Daga
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```